# Error when trying to extract values from a raster layer to each shapefile using R

Tags: r, extract, raster, shapefile

I'm trying to extract the values from a raster layer to a shapefile layer, but the process is extremely time consuming, but 2 hours without me getting any result. In general considering the size of the polygons and the raster this process should not take more than two 2 minutes in cases that I had already done.

the message I get is this:
`no loop for break/next, jumping to top level`

my code is this:

```
library(sf)
library(raster)

#shapefile geometry
shp <- sf::st_read("/vsicurl/http://wesleysc352.github.io/seg_s3_r3_m10_fix_estat_amost_val.shp")

#raster geotiff
raster3<-raster::raster("http://wesleysc352.github.io/1final.tif")

#extract values
ext1<-raster::extract(raster3, shp)
```

OBS Edit: links for reproducible example:

shape https://github.com/wesleysc352/wesleysc352.github.io/raw/master/seg_s3_r3_m10_fix_estat_amost_val.zip

raster
https://github.com/wesleysc352/wesleysc352.github.io/raw/master/1final.tif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exact_extract` from the `exactextractr` package. It takes 5 seconds:

```
> system.time({ext1<-exact_extract(raster3, shp)})
  |======================================================================| 100%
   user  system elapsed 
  4.805   0.296   5.103
```

and gives you a list of data frames of pixel numbers and fractional coverage:

```
> head(ext1[[1]])
  value coverage_fraction
1     4              0.25
2     4              0.50
3     4              0.50
4     4              0.25
5     4              0.25
6     4              0.75
> head(ext1[[2]])
  value coverage_fraction
1     4              0.25
2     4              0.50
3     4              0.25
4     4              0.50
5     4              1.00
6     4              0.50
[etc]
```

which is more than `extract` gives you (a list of pixel values only).

Why is it slow? Don't know, can't really see the point finding out when `exactextractr` exists. If you want to know, try subsets of your polygons. For example the first ten rows takes:

```
> system.time({ext10<-extract(raster3, shp[1:10,])})
   user  system elapsed 
  2.549   0.029   2.574
```

2.57 seconds, which extrapolates to:

```
> nrow(shp)
[1] 2308
> 2.5*2308/10
[1] 577
```

577 seconds for the lot. If the full set is still going after ten minutes I'd split it in parts and see if maybe there's an odd polygon with bad geometry that's messing it all up. But in that time you could have run `exact_extract` about 200 times and played a round of golf/gone fishing/engaged in pleasant leisure activity of your choice.

Comment: It doesn't run and still shows the error `Error: 'inMemory' is not an exported object from 'namespace:terra'`, which could be. I tried to do  `ext1<-exactextractr::exact_extract(raster3, shp)`, but without success

Comment: How on earth did the `terra` package get involved there? Is this from a clean R session with no other packages attached?

Comment: even with a clean section and after restarting R, I have this message. The land package was not even declared.

Comment: Looks like something broken in your R setup. Tried re-installing relevant packages and trying again? Edit your Q to show the version numbers of everything, and download the data to work from local files instead of remote http or vsicurl links.

Comment: I tested it on another totally clean machine without having other packages installed like `terra` and it worked. It gives me a list() with the values. Now I found another problem. thanks greetings.

Comment: new feedback: I found the problem. I was trying to carry out the process in a session (tab) of R that was already in use previously, where the `terra` package had already been requested. This session is not saved, but an image was being saved in ~/.RData. So every time I loaded Rstudio it retrieved that section. I solved it by creating a new blank rmarkdown and closing all previously opened sessions.